# Tengo un formulario en Php y quiero que un campo input box permita pegar caracteres numericos pero que restrinja letras

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario en Php y quiero que un campo input box permita pegar caracteres numericos(ctrl-c seguido ctrl-v) pero que restrinja letras(el campo solo debe permitir numeros sea escribiendo(onkeypress) o pegando datos de otra fuente:

```
<input name="telefono" type="text" id="telefono" placeholder="telefono" tabindex="3" title="Telefono">
```

Este es el script:

```
<script>
function Numeros(string){//Solo numeros
    var out = '';
    var filtro = '1234567890';//Caracteres validos

    //Recorrer el texto y verificar si el caracter se encuentra en la lista de validos 
    for (var i=0; i<string.length; i++)
       if (filtro.indexOf(string.charAt(i)) != -1) 
             //Se añaden a la salida los caracteres validos
         out += string.charAt(i);

    //Retornar valor filtrado
    return out;
} 

</script>
```

Comment: Hola Eduardo. ¿Y qué has intentado?  Recuerda que aqui ayudamos a solucionar problemas pero una vez intentados. Investiga e intenta implementarlo y si tienes problemas concretos pregunta siguiendo [ask]. Te sugiero que mires el atributo `Pattern` o el evento `onChange` para detectar todos los cambios en el contenido del input. Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda investigare los atibutos que comentas, saludos

Comment: Mira tambien en vez de `type="text"` , usar  `type="number"` para que no deje escribir letras

Comment: Estoy explorando una alternativa de hacerlo por una funcion de java

Comment: Añade el codigo a la pregunta pulsando en [edit]. No en los comentarios ;)